# failing to load after 5 minutes

Tags: jxbrowser

I have seen similar posts in the past which suggest the issue is resolved but i still see this once in a while in version 5.4.3. Why does this happen and is there a way to avoid this? Browser is created in a separate Thread to avoid UI getting blocked for 5 minutes

Caused by: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserException: Failed to load 'about:blank' web page within 300 seconds.
        at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.(Unknown Source)

Comment: It happened on a Windows 7 and a Mac 10.9.5 machine

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that JxBrowser didn't receive response from Chromium process during Browser instance instantiation. Usually it happens because Chromium process failed to start or it was blocked by some anti-virus software. Please make sure that Chromium process isn't blocked, and Java and Chromium process can use local ports. Sometimes firewall software can block communication via local socket ports that are used by JxBrowser.